# How can I remove Punctuation in a Wordcloud?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, word-cloud

We tried to do a wordcloud, however we already removed punctuation but we still have a comma in the wordcloud.

We used the following code:

```
text1+=i + ' '

wc = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800,background_color="white",min_font_size = 10,\
repeat=True,)
wc.generate(text1)
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None)
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(wc, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.title('Sentiment Reviews English',fontsize=32);
```

Comment: Not knowing how text was preprocessed, it is more likely that not all punctuation was removed rather than WordCloud introducing new punctuation, so it would be really helpful if you could provide code you used to remove punctuation. Also (if possible), current output you get would also be useful in answering your question.

Comment: We need to see your input `text1`. Otherwise this question is not reproducible [mcve]. Also, you might as well show the output plot (or else its underlying strings).

Answer (score -1):

NLTK is very useful for processing texts by removing punctuation or stop-words (which might interest you for your word cloud).

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokenizer.tokenize('Sentiment . Reviews, English!')
#['Sentiment', 'Reviews', 'English']
```